# Jhipster Angular Gateway - passing filter to routing menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jhipster

I have a JHipster gateway with standard navbar.
I have one Entity and I need to filter it following one String parameter:

```js
export interface IPayment {
  id?: number;
  code?: string;
  payType?: PayType;
  date...
  
with PayType an enum:
export const enum PayType {
  A = 'Paypal',
  B = 'Applepay',
  C = ...
}
```

So in my navbar.component.html there is:

```html
<li>
    <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="payment/A" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" (click)="collapseNavbar()">
    <fa-icon icon="asterisk" fixedWidth="true"></fa-icon>
                            <span jhiTranslate="global.menu.entities.paymentA">See Paypal payments</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="payment/B" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" (click)="collapseNavbar()">
    <fa-icon icon="asterisk" fixedWidth="true"></fa-icon>
                            <span jhiTranslate="global.menu.entities.paymentB">See Applepay payments</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

In this manner I have a single html/ts showing Paypal, Applepay, other type of payment following the link filtered (A/B/C/...).
I try this using routing inserting `path: 'A', component:..., resolve:..., data:..., canActivate:...` but I see a strange behavior. When click over the menu item, start many call. The first one goes ok, but the other are full of errors (org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property found for type ...undefined...).

Who is the thing calling the other times? How can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved making a different approach.

Not using the routing for separate the calling, but using components.ts ngOnInit method to add a filter/criteria used in the loadAll method:

```js
loadAll() {
    this.myService
      .query({...this.myCriteria,
```